# Does the morning after scene from the trailer of season 2 of Skam fit into the actual story of the season?

Tags: trailers, skam

In the [trailer (NSFW)](https://tv.nrk.no/serie/skam/msub19118616#) for [Season 2](https://tv.nrk.no/serie/skam/mynt15000116/sesong-2/episode-1) of [Skam](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5288312/), Noora is shown waking up naked in some strange apartment after what seems to have been quite a crazy party.

In the actual season, however, I don't recall that scene ever taking place. Moreover, I don't see any place in the chronology where that would really fit into the story either. It resembles episode 9 a little bit, where Noora wakes up at Niko's place. However, in that episode, William wasn't there, yet William shows up in the trailer.

So, I'm not sure if the trailer fits into the chronology at all. So, what is the deal with the trailer? I remember reading about the creator of the series saying that she used to change the story as she went. Maybe the event from the trailer was originally intended to be a part of the story, but then it was changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what the trailer was getting at was Noora's fear of just being another one of William's conquests. I think the naked girls were all meant to represent his past hook ups (I also think the blonde girl in the bed next to her is vilde and the fact those two are in the bed together represents noora and vilde's relationship and how it develops during season 2 because of William). All the sex toys, booze and cigarettes might be a shoutout to his bad boy image and the rumours that surround William that we heard in season 1. I think really it's just about Noora opening herself up to something she feels might destroy the walls that she put up around herself but thats how I feel now watching it back

Comment: Good analysis, welcome to Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the trailer it is more of a series of references that have throughout the season. Producers can not show much, right? So I think they are different elements that tell the story of the second season as:
-The appearance of William, proposing that he would have a focus this season.
-The blonde on her side in the bed, which is Vilde to me.
-The fact that she was at this seemingly crazy party, that it would be such a complete turnaround in her life.
But of course the scene is very similar to the one in which she wakes up on the side of William's brother ...
This is my opinion :)